# How to edit and save a file from MS-DOS under meterpreter?

Tags: meterpreter

Once I have a meterpreter shell on the machine, I opened a MS-DOS prompt with this command:

```
execute -f cmd.exe -i -H
```

Then, I would like to edit a file with `edit file_name`, but I don't know how to save the file (normally you have to use the MS-DOS menu but there is no such thing in a meterpreter session).

Do you have any idea how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: For the record: `cmd.exe` **IS NOT** a MS-DOS shell. MS-DOS was a 16-bit real-mode non-multi-tasking operating system that used a command-line shell called `command.com`. While `cmd.exe` shares much (*though not all*) of its syntax with `command.com` and as a consequence DOS `.bat` files will usually work on it, it is a 32-bit Windows binary that supports multi-tasking (and does not run on MS-DOS). If you're running `cmd.exe` then you are on Windows, not DOS, and *the title of your question is wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to not edit the file on the target box but on the attacking box, you can easily do this by the two meterpreter commands upload / download and a local editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out meterpreter's [`edit`](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-basics/) command:

> The ‘edit‘ command opens a file located on the target host. It uses
>   the ‘vim’ so all the editor’s commands are available.
>
> Please refer to the “vim” editor documentation for more advance [dic]use.
>   http://www.vim.org/

This should be issued in the meterpreter shell, not the command shell (i.e. before you run `execute`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much editing you need to do, you can use `echo` with output redirection (`>` to overwrite a file with your output, `>>` to append to a file) to edit a file. For example,

```
echo This line will replace the contents of this file > file1.txt
echo This line will be appended to the file's end >> file2.txt
```

If you need to do more fine-grained editing than that and you're on a modern Windows version, you can use `powershell`, which gives you a much more powerful scripting engine (although you will still need to script out the editing). If you were actually on DOS (you aren't!), or are on a 32-bit Windows version, you could use [`edlin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edlin). You do not want to use `edlin`.

Of course, since what you're actually trying to do is "edit a file via meterpreter", which has *nothing to do* with `cmd.exe` much less MS-DOS, you should just use meterpreter's `edit` command, as the other answers say.